# I want to edit images in flutter with text on top of the images

Tags: flutter, image

I was wondering what is the right way of doing this? Should I use built-in widgets like stack, positioned, opacity, etc and store it’s values in firestore and then when I download the image from firebase storage with the url I add the overlay with the variables I stored in firestore regarding postion, opacity and so on? Or is there a way to save the image in firebase storage already with the edited text as one combined picture? Thanks for your help

Comment: There are many different sources that explain such integration - e.g this package should achieve that: https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor